# Android INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS stays visible only on Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My current android application uses `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)`
which works fine on my android v4.4.2 device, however on my v4.0.3 device the action bar spinner is visible all the time
Even after adding in a call to `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);` the spinner is still visible.
My Min SDK = 14; Target SDK = 19.
what do i need to do to get control of when the spinner is visible?

Comment: Is your Activity extending something besides Activity?

Comment: Yes, BaseGameActivity. Why does that make a difference though?

Comment: It can make a difference. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);` instead. 
It is the Support library version of the method you are calling. 
And make sure your `BaseGameActivity` extends `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: nice idea, i cannot think why i didnt think of this :-)

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of the indeterminate progress indicator changed. In Ice Cream Sandwich and earlier, it defaults to on. In Jelly Bean and later, it defaults to off.

If you don't want to use the `appcompat-v7` library, simply add `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);` to your `onCreate()`, but make sure you do so *after* the `setContentView(...)` call or it won't work.